# Regex replace in Spyder with case conversion

Tags: python, regex, spyder

I would like to convert a string from `camelCase` to `snake_case` using regex. I could do this using python through the terminal or a text editor I am more familiar with, but I would like to know if this is possible in the built-in search and replace of Spyder. 
I am able to catch the groups, using

```
Pattern:      ([a-z])([A-Z])
Replace with: \1\2
```

, but not to convert the case like I read [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html).

Comment: Has a regex answer